# Error installing MySql: E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt, package-management, mysql

I can't install MySql. When I install sudo apt install mysql-server, I get an error.

In the past I received this error that blocked any type of update for any software, but I solved the problem and everything came back ok, I could install any software ..... except MySql. Even now it is like that. How can I install Mysql on Linux Mint latest version?

```
There were errors in processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

More precisely, I receive:

```
After this operation, 204 MB of disk space will be occupied.
To continue? [Y / n] s

Download of: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 mysql-client-core-8.0 amd64 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [4.423 kB]
Download of: 2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 mysql-client-8.0 amd64 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [22.0 kB]
Download of: 3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 mysql-server-core-8.0 amd64 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [18.4 MB]
Download of: 4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 mysql-server-8.0 amd64 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [1.313 kB]
Download of: 5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 mysql-server all 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [9.548 B]
Retrieved 24.2 MB in 5s (4,538 kB / s)
Pre-configuration of packages in progress
Selected the mysql-client-core-8.0 package not previously selected.
(Database reading ... 641576 currently installed files and directories.)
Preparations to extract ... / mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Extracting mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selected the mysql-client-8.0 package not previously selected.
Preparations to extract ... / mysql-client-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Extracting mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selected the mysql-server-core-8.0 package not previously selected.
Preparations to extract ... / mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Extracting mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Preparations to extract ... / mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...

grep: / etc / mysql /: File or directory does not exist
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpac
k):
 mysql-server-8.0 pre-installation script new package thread returned error status 1
Selected the mysql-server package not previously selected.
Preparations to extract ... / mysql-server_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Extraction of mysql-server (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
There were errors in processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Is this only while installing MySQL or everything , what is result of apt upgrade and running `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` will fix the apt issue

Comment: @Algnis only while installing MySQL